Should timer capture full time for list creation?
Following this Python context manager that measures time I tried myself.
from time import perf_counter


class catchtime:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = perf_counter()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.time = perf_counter() - self.start
        self.readout = f"Time: {self.time:.3f} seconds"
        print(self.readout)


with catchtime() as timer:
    a = [1] * 1000000000
    print(1)

print(timer.readout)

The thing is even after timing is finished, the python program does not stop executing until a few seconds later. I read that is related to memory and garbage collection. Can anyone explain to me this and if the timer should actually capture the full time?

First, as you said, Python will do something related to memory and garbage collection by its cleanup handlers, which is called cleanup actions. Such as running finally clauses of try statements, flushing the i/o buffers, destroying every single object, closing threads and child processes, freeing memories allocated by librarys, etc.
Second, you can use os._exit() to quit Python immediately without doing any cleanup by Python itself. It is like a kill command on linux or a taskkill command on windows.  It's not recommended since it is
rough and aggressive.
Third, if you really want to capture the full time, I suggest monitoring the progress of the python codes by another progress.
